# opencv throwing an error in macOS - Mojave

Tags: python, macos, opencv, ubuntu, webcam

**macOS - mojave**
,
opencv-python = 4.1.0.25
, python = 3.5.6

When I try to open the webcam to capture the image through opencv in macOS-Mojave, I am constantly getting this error.

But running the same script in ubuntu and windows, there is no error I encounter.

Here is my test code

'''

```
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)
window_name = "Capture"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vs.set(3, 1280)
vs.set(4, 720)
time.sleep(2.0)
total = 0

msg = "Enter your Name"
title = "Siamese Network Training Module"
fieldNames = ["Name"]
fieldValues = []
**fieldValues = multenterbox(msg,title, fieldNames)**
folder_names = fieldValues[0]
new_output_folder = output + folder_names
print(new_output_folder)
```

'''

and this is the error at bold line highlighted above

'''

```
  First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4a599a7d __exceptionPreprocess + 256
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff74c6aa17 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4a613886 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4a53b8ef ___forwarding___ + 1485
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4a53b298 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000012717d31d TkpInit + 413
6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x00000001270d517e Initialize + 2622
7   _tkinter.cpython-35m-darwin.so      0x00000001171799f6 _tkinter_create + 1174
8   python                              0x000000010b84455e PyCFunction_Call + 62
9   python                              0x000000010b90bec7 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 18583
.
.
.
.
42  python                              0x000000010b957eee PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 382
43  python                              0x000000010b97cd86 Py_Main + 3622
44  python                              0x000000010b7be861 main + 497
45  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff764383d5 start + 1
46  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
  )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

'''

Please let me know what can be done. Thanks